# Sample reviews?

Tags: discussion

I've just gotten reviewer status, and while I'm more than willing to help out, I'm reluctant to do so in fear that I'd shank the review. Would it be possible to get some sample reviews posted?

Comment: Kudos for thinking about this. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congratulations on hitting the mile stone.  There is actually already a way to do this.  When you are looking at the review page, hit the "Recent Reviews" link and then go to the History tab.  ([Low Quality Posts](https://photo.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) for example.)  It will show you the recent review votes for that category so you can get an idea what to do.

Also, don't be too worried about it.  No action is taken on your review alone.  It has to be matched by what other people think.  About the only thing that goes directly is editing once you hit 2000 rep, but you still have a ways to go before you hit that privilege.  Currently, all your actions will require agreement by multiple other community members.

You can also always consider jumping in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photography-chat) to ask for guidance if you are still unsure about something and want some more feedback.